# Comparison channel impulse in DD and TF domains

Tags: matlab, time-frequency, delay, channel, doppler

How can I plot a similar comparison plot in Matlab?

[image]

**My attempt**

I have tried to create a random function like/ Matlab:

`rand(M, N)`

and then take SFFT of it

`fft(ifft(rand(M, N)))`

and plot them using bar3 function in Matlab

[image]

Comment: You are just plotting random data. Why do you think that has anything to do with Doppler ?

Comment: If your question is just about plotting, it should be asked over at stackoverflow. (Maybe  you're looking for `surf`?)

Comment: @Hilmar I want visual representation data in time-frequency and delay-doppler domain. Is it wrong what I did?